# How to find the $(S ,T)$ for which the objective function $C$ will be maximized?

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

I have been given the following problem.

Maximize $C = S+T$  using duality

Subject to the $S + 3T \geq 8$ and $3S + T \geq 8 , S,T \geq 0.$

The duality of this problem is following.

Minimize $C' = 8S' + 8T'$ using duality

Subject to the $S' + 3T' \leq 1$ and $3S' + T' \leq 1 , S,T \geq 0.$

I have solved this by using Graphical method. I got Min $C' = 4$ when $(S' , T') = (\frac{1}{4} , \frac{1}{4})$.

So I can say Max $C=4$ . But what will be $(S , T)$ for which Max $C=4$ ? Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By complementary slackness condition, we have

$$S'(S+3T-8)=0$$

$$T'(3S+T-8)=0$$

Hence knowing that $S'$ and $T'$ are non-zero, we have

$$S'>0 \implies S+3T=8$$
$$T' >0 \implies3S+T=8$$

Solving the simultaneous equation, we get $S=T=2$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how I get $(S, T)$ ? I know S'  = T'  = 0.25

Comment: I have included more details of complementary slackness condition.

Comment: Now it is clear. Thank You